# RMI server terminates after a while

Tags: java, eclipse, rmi

I run my test RMI server from Eclipse.
Currently, it just consists of the implementation of my RMI interface (IRDSA) with a very few methods and the server itself implemented in this main:
(Using a private port number)

```
    static Registry registry;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // start Registry
        try {
            registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(RMI_PORT);
        } catch (ExportException exp) {
            System.out.format ("RMI Registry (Port %d) already active. Providing", RMI_PORT);
            try {
                Registry    existingReg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(RMI_PORT);
                String[] bound = existingReg.list();
                for (String entry : bound)
                    System.out.println (entry);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            return;
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        try {
            IRDSA server = new RDSAServer();
            IRDSA stub = (IRDSA) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(server, 0);

            // Bind the remote object's stub in the registry
            registry.bind(RMI_NAME, stub);

            System.out.println("RDSAServer ready");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("RDSAServer exception: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

For a test, I start a local client and it executes the methods well.
This can be repeated and the server remains alive, no matter that main has finished already.
But after a while, even if I keep a client connected (suspended in a break), when I return from lunch the client is still suspended but the server is terminated silently.

When des it happen exactly, and how can I avoid it?

Found a similar question, where the Registry should be static (it is, here)

Do I have to keep main alive?

Anything else?

Comment: Shouldn't happen. Try making the server object or the stub static.

Comment: Seems making both registry and stub static helps. Thanks @EJP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Server-Application only consists of the main-method where you start and bind your RMI-Server. The RMI-Server will only live as long there are stub-instances where the client's calls go on. If they are garbage-collected, the server will be shut down by the JVM.

For easy purposes, you can use a loop in your main-method so the Main-Thread will not end and also your RMI-Server will be kept alive.

Comment: Thanks. main now ends in <p>...<br>System.out.println("RDSAServer ready\nPress Enter to Exit");
  System.in.read(); }

Comment: But the client is still alive, so the server object shouldn't be garbage-collected. It shouldn't be necessary to keep anything else alive.

Comment: If client exits, keeping server main alive is certainly the better way. RMI server will have to run as a windows service (daemon) in the long term anyway.

Answer (score 0):

hopefully this one help you,
The Java Remote Method Invocation (Java RMI) is a Java API that performs remote method invocation, the object-oriented equivalent of remote procedure calls (RPC), with support for direct transfer of serialized Java classes and distributed garbage collection.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation

Comment: This is correct, but I don's see how your sentence can help me ;)